# Php get method data url to filename/id

Tags: php

I have a this page **get_cost.php** and when URL gets **GET** method **"id"** data it will be like this **get_cost.php?id=4**. So I want to change this url like this **website.com/get_cost/4** what I must do for this in php?

Comment: [pretty url php](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pretty+url+php&oq=pretty+url+php&aqs=chrome..69i57.272j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already answered many times before. First you must search your question in site. 
You can do it with **RewriteRule**. You must use **.htaccess** code for this. To get this add this code to your **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^get_cost/([0-9]+)/ get_cost.php?id=$1
```

If your filename different you can change `get_cost` from the code.

Comment: where htaccess file is placed?

Comment: Create a file named .htaccess (with dot) in root folder of your site in a localserver or hosting and add above code.

Comment: windows did not allowed to put dot to front of the name. What I must do?

Comment: You can use Notepad++ to rename it or create new file named with .htaccess

Comment: Thanks! It done ! )